# getting two kinds of data and display it out

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table called "profile" in mysql database
Table structure:

```
user | hasimg | imgurl
```

As you can see "hasimg" and "imgurl", normally if a user does not have an image, `hasimg` will be set to `0` and `imgurl` is set to none.

On the other hand, if a user has an image assigned then `hasimg` is set to `1` and `imgurl` will contain the link.

- How can I display ones that have images (`hasimg` set to 1) with `<img src="imgurl` html tags?
- How can I display ones that **do not** have images (`hasimg` set to 0) , without `<img src`?

I want to make a list which display users with images and user that does not have image.

Here's the code im using to echo out the data row by row

```
   <?php

      $sql = "SELECT * FROM profile ORDER BY user DSC"; 
      $query = mysql_query($sql)or die(mysql_error());

               $rows = array();
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $query )){
          $rows[] = $row;
          echo "User:$row[user]<br>Image:$row[hasimg]\n";
        }

    ?>
```

P/S mysql connection established.

Comment: i have tried php while to echo out the data from each row. but im not sure how to let php differentiate which one has an img and which one dont when using WHILE.

Comment: Please check my example given in the answer.

Comment: Proper [sample code](http://sscce.org/) (here, SQL statements) is more useful than any ad hoc schema and sample data format. Please use `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT ... VALUES` for samples. Desired results don't need to be presented as sample code, as results are the output of code and not code themselves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep your layout fancy way you can use default image.

```
if($hasimg == 0)
   $imgurl = "default.jpg";

echo '<img src="' . $imgurl . '">';
```

EDIT:

Your PHP code could be like this.

```
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM profile ORDER BY user DSC"; 
 $result = mysql_query($sql)or die(mysql_error());


echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Image</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
    $imgurl = $row['imgurl'];
    if($row['hasimg'] == 0)
         $imgurl = "default.jpg";

      echo "<tr>";
      echo "<td>" . $row['user'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td><img src=\"" .$imgurl . "'\" /></td>";
      echo "</tr>";
  }
echo "</table>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Two solutions:

1. Set a pathway to default img jpg file as default field content to field `imgurl` in your database.
2. Filter query results by adding this code just after `$rows[] = $row;`:

   ```
   If ($row['hasimg'] == 0) $row['imgurl'] = 'default.jpg';
   ```